# How can I expand XML abbreviations in a PHP string with PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

I've recently switched from Notepad++ to PHPStorm and I've been able to get most features that I had in Notepad++ working.

The one I can't figure out is expanding an abbreviation inside a PHP string (or anywhere outside of an xml context).

For example, in Notepad++ with the Zen Coding plugin:

```
$link = "button.btn-large>i.fa.fa-facebook+span.btn-text|";
```

If I stick my cursor at the end of the string, where the pipe is, and press CTRL+E, it expands that entire string something like:

```
<button class="btn-large">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
   <span class="btn-text"></span>
</button>
```

... And this doesn't work in PHPStorm.

The expand key is TAB, and as you expect, it enters a tab. I looked for a hotkey to forcefully expand XML, but I didn't find one. I saw there is something called live previews - but I'm not making a macro. I just want to expand abbreviations.

**UPDATE:**

One partial solution is to go to "Live Templates" > "Zen HTML", then select an abbreviation. At the bottom there's an "Applicable in HTML, (etc)".

You can achieve this by clicking "Change" and adding "PHP String Literal".

But you have to do it for every element one at a time. It's not a very elegant solution. I'm really hoping there is a better way.

Comment: As you have noticed yourself -- it has to be a valid context. My only suggestions: **1)** inject correct language into a string literal manually (same disadvantage -- needs to be done manually); **2)** Use HEREDOCs (instead of plain string) where correct language can be injected automatically, e.g. `$link = <<<XML ...` **3)** You could try "Emmet Everywhere" plugin -- may work. too bad that latest plugin version requires Java 1.8 while I'm using 1.7 and therefore cannot confirm if it will do the job (it should).

Comment: **4)** Another suggestion: enter such strings in a separate file (be it real file or Scratch one) where context is valid and then just copy generated text back. Considering that IDE allows to have multiple edit windows / split windows, having scratch file opened on the bottom will not eat tons of screen space and may be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, the plugin "emmet everywhere" sounds exactly like what I want. I haven't tried abbreviations in a heredoc yet. I'll try these out today!

Comment: Unfortunately Emmet Everywhere doesn't seem to work even after changing hotkey and using Java 1.8. #2 Using a heredoc named "<<<html" seems to work. Not preferable for single-line strings though, but good to know! #4 is similar to #1 in using language injection, if you click the light bulb when editing in HTML context you can "edit html fragment". This is exactly what you described, built in. None of them are an exact match to what I'm used to, but these tricks should help. thanks!

Comment: *"...and using Java 1.8"* -- any proofs that 1.8 was actually used by IDE? The Java version used can be seen in `Help | About` screen. *" #4 is similar to #1 in using language injection"* -- not really -- if you have html file opened in separate tab .. it already has HTML context so no language injection (injection of **another** language into some element/place) gets involved. But yes, generally speaking, each language injection fragment is treated like separate document.

Comment: Ah, the IDE is using 1.7 apparently. I had typed `java -version` to check before. I didn't think it would prefer the old version. Thanks for the tip! I'll look into getting phpstorm to use the newer version of java tomorrow.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: If you want to post this information (especially about Emmet Everywhere) in an answer, I'll accept it.